# Storing API KEY in .env and fetching it in react app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I've a `.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=1234567
```

Then I added that to my `component`:

```
const API_kEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
console.log("Key is", API_KEY);
const URL = "http://myapi.com?appid=${API_KEY}"
```

I get API key in console successfully, but I get this error:

> dashboard.js:26 GET [http://myapi.com?appid=${API_KEY}](http://myapi.com?appid=$%7BAPI_KEY%7D) 401 (Unauthorized)

How can I make URL to get the API KEY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that you are using double quotes. Instead of using double quotes, you need to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

With double quotes, your URL is literally

```
"http://myapi.com?appid=${API_KEY}"
```

but it should be

```
"http://myapi.com?appid=1234567"
```

#### Solution

Replace double quotes around the URL with backticks

```
const URL = `http://myapi.com?appid=${API_KEY}`
```

Alternatively, you could just concatenate the API key with the URL

```
const URL = "http://myapi.com?appid=" + API_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use Template Literals (Backtick) here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
const API_kEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
console.log("Key is", API_KEY);
const URL = `http://myapi.com?appid=${API_KEY}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for weatherApp

.env

```
REACT_APP_KEY=04a1f006349043f7ae3145707222012
REACT_APP_URL= http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?aqi=no
```

Async Await Function:

```
async function loadInfo(city="london") {
    try {
        const request= await fetch(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_KEY}&q=${city}`
        );
        const json = await request.json();
      console.log(json);
    } catch (error) {

    }

}
```